# Bitmap won't rotate on point

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap

I have a polygon that is generated from a bitmap. I'm trying to draw the bitmap onto the polygon but can't figure out why it's not working.

It works when there is no rotation. But apply rotation and it goes out of the centre.

[image: Rotation problem]

Code for drawing the bitmap

```
mMatrix.setScale(this.mPolygon.getScaleX(), this.mPolygon.getScaleY());
//Could be wrong, maybe it's the topLeft. it needs.
mMatrix.setTranslate(
         this.getDimensions().centerX() - (this.getDimensions().width() / 2f),
         this.getDimensions().centerY() - (this.getDimensions().height() / 2f)
);

mMatrix.postRotate(this.getRotation(), this.getDimensions().centerX(), this.getDimensions().centerY());
canvas.drawBitmap(this.mBitmap, mMatrix, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem it's because the bitmap is different dimensions to the polygon. Heres the code that works.

```
mMatrix.reset();
mMatrix.setTranslate(
     this.getDimensions().centerX() - (this.mBitmap.getWidth() / 2),
     this.getDimensions().centerY() - (this.mBitmap.getHeight() / 2));
mMatrix.postRotate (getRotation(), this.getDimensions().centerX(), this.getDimensions().centerY());
mMatrix.postScale(this.mPolygon.getScaleX(), this.mPolygon.getScaleY());
canvas.drawBitmap(this.mBitmap, mMatrix, null);
```